# Pass nsmutablearray from one viewcontroller to another view controller

Tags: iphone, ios

Here I am adding values to nsmutablearray in the firstviewcontroller. When I click UIButton I want pass this array to another view controller.

```
AppointmentClass *appObj = [[AppointmentClass alloc]init];
appObj.subject = [key objectForKey:@"Subject"];
appObj.location = [key objectForKey:@"Location"];
appObj.scheduledStart = [key objectForKey:@"ScheduledStart"];
appObj.scheduledEnd = [key objectForKey:@"ScheduledEnd"];
[firstNameArray addObject:appObj];            
[appObj release];
appObj=nil;
```

When I passing firstnamearray value to appointmentdataarray.

```
secondviewcontroller *appointmentViewObject = [[secondviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
[appointmentViewObject setAppointmentDataArray:firstNameArray];
```

From the above the appointmentdataarray returning a null value.

```
[self presentModalViewController:appointmentViewObject animated:YES];
[appointmentViewObject release];
```

Comment: check firstNameArray  alloc or not?

Comment: yes firstNameArray is alloc

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: skip presentModalViewController. and once try [self.navigationcontroller pushviewController:animated:]; method

Answer (score 0):

Have you allocated the array?

```
NSMutableArray* firstNameArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: What type of property is AppointmentDataArray on the secondViewController? It should be strong or retain.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one thing:
in `secondviewcontroller.m` add a following method:

```
-(id) initwithnibName:(NSString*)_nib withArray:(NSMutableArray*)_array{

  self = [super initWithNibName:_nib bundle:nil];

if (self) {
    self.array =_array;
}
return self;

}
```

and add `-(id) initwithnibName:(NSString*)_nib withArray:(NSMutableArray*)_array;` to `secondviewcontroller.h`.

Now replace `secondviewcontroller *appointmentViewObject = [[secondviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
[appointmentViewObject setAppointmentDataArray:firstNameArray];`

with `secondviewcontroller *appointmentViewObject = [[secondviewcontroller alloc]initwithnibName:@"secondviewcontroller" withArray:firstNameArray];`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying statement:

```
  [appointmentViewObject setAppointmentDataArray:firstNameArray];
```

With this:

```
  [appointmentViewObject setAppointmentDataArray:[NSArray arrayWithArray:firstNameArray]];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

secondviewcontroller.h file

```
 NSMutableArray* AppointmentDataArray;

 @property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray* AppointmentDataArray;
 -(void)setMyArray:(NSMutableArray *)arr;
```

secondviewcontroller.m file

```
 @synthesize AppointmentDataArray;

 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
            bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
      if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil 
                            bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
         // Custom initialization.
           AppointmentDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       }
    return self;
  }

   -(void)setMyArray:(NSMutableArray *)arr{
          AppointmentDataArray=arr;
    }
```

///////When you push

```
   secondviewcontroller *appointmentViewObject = [[secondviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
   [appointmentViewObject setMyArray:firstNameArray];
   [self presentModalViewController:appointmentViewObject animated:YES];
```